# Function is returning a set of ints instead of adding the ints

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, sum, tuples

So I have a function `count_by_type(db, stype)` where I have to count how many single and dual type Pokemon with types that match stype exist, count them, and then sum it into an int.

Given a dict called db with a format like so:

```
    sample_db = {
"Bulbasaur": (1, "Grass", "Poison", 45, 49, 49, 45, 1, False),
"Charmander": (4, "Fire", None, 39, 52, 43, 65, 1, False),
"Charizard": (6, "Fire", "Flying", 78, 84, 78,100, 1, False),
"Moltres": (146, "Fire", "Flying", 90,100, 90, 90, 1, True),
"Crobat": (169, "Poison", "Flying", 85, 90, 80,130, 2, False),
"Tornadus, (Incarnate Form)": (641, "Flying", None, 79,115, 70,111, 5, True),
"Reshiram": (643, "Dragon", "Fire", 100,120,100, 90, 5, True)
}
```

I implemented some code to do what was described above. Here:

```
def count_by_type(db, stype):
    single_type_count = 0
    dual_type_count = 0
    total_count = 0
    for pokemon in db:
        if (db[pokemon][1] == stype and db[pokemon][2] != stype) or (db[pokemon][1] != stype and db[pokemon][2] == stype):
            single_type_count += 1
        if (db[pokemon][1]== stype or db[pokemon][2] == stype):
            dual_type_count += 1
total_count = single_type_count + dual_type_count
return total_count
```

The problem is that it is returning a set like (1,2,3) or (4,0,4) instead of adding the counters so it would return 6 or 8 respectively.

EDIT: Actually I returned a single integer and I NEED to return the value in a way that matches the set notation. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself, silly mistake: All you have to do is create a variable and set it equal to a tuple. So in this case it would be totaltuple = ((single_type_count, dual_type_count, total_count)